# Starting Ettercap is giving me an error

Tags: terminal

I have been stuck finding this problem online for the past 5 days, and I couldn't find an answer, everytime I start ettercap and choose my interface as wlan0 it gives me an error, like this one

```
ERROR: 9, Bad file descriptor
[/build/ettercap-jPFHOw/ettercap-08.2/src/ec_network.c:source_init:245]
libnet_init: unknown physical layer type 0x323
```

I don't even have the ec_network.c file, or the libnet file (if that is relevant to this problem) if I need to download it, where can I download it from?

Thanks

Comment: What command you are using?  And how `ip addr show` looks?  I can replicate that by specifying an interface that is not connected.  e.g. `ettercap -T -i enp3s0 /192.168.0.90/80` where `enp3s0` is not connected to anything.

Comment: The interface is up and running, wlan0 is capable of going into monitor mode, seeing traffic, injections, etc.. I can only use ettercap with eth0, but not with wlan0. Maybe it's a problem with the files, libnet or ec_network.c

Comment: Hmm... I'm looking at the code in `net/if_arp.h` and there is no such thing as `0x323`.  You changed the MAC address of the card, right?

Comment: No, I just plugged it in, without changing the settings, so I don't think I changed the MAC address

Comment: I was searching for the `if_arp.h` file but I didn't find it, is it possible that I'm missing some things?

Comment: On `linux` is is in `/usr/include/net/if_arp.h` (if you use linux and do not have that file things are bad).  Basically that `0x323` is compared against he defines in that file but results from `ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family` where `ifr_hwaddr` is a `struct sockaddr`.  That thing is setup with `ioctl` but I am not very confident how exactly the MAC is parsed before being placed in there.  I'd try playing around changing the MAC and seeing if the `0x323` changes.  I'll probably write a small program to test this but that will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have found a kernel bug.  Maybe I should not go as far as naming it a bug, since it could just be that support for the specific identifier of the card was never added into the kernel code.

The ettercap code dealing with the physical layer is as follows:

```
 switch (ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family)
 {
     case ARPHRD_ETHER:
     case ARPHRD_METRICOM:
#ifdef ARPHRD_LOOPBACK
     case ARPHRD_LOOPBACK:   
#endif
         l->link_type = DLT_EN10MB;
         l->link_offset = 0xe;
         break;
     case ARPHRD_SLIP:
     case ARPHRD_CSLIP:
     case ARPHRD_SLIP6:
     case ARPHRD_CSLIP6:
     case ARPHRD_PPP:
         l->link_type = DLT_RAW;
         break;
     case ARPHRD_FDDI:
         l->link_type   = DLT_FDDI;
         l->link_offset = 0x15;
         break;
     /* Token Ring */
     case ARPHRD_IEEE802:
     case ARPHRD_IEEE802_TR:
     case ARPHRD_PRONET:
         l->link_type   = DLT_PRONET;
         l->link_offset = 0x16;
         break;

     default:
         snprintf(l->err_buf, LIBNET_ERRBUF_SIZE,
             "unknown physical layer type 0x%x",
             ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family);
     goto bad;
 }
```

And you can check the values of all those defines inside `/usr/include/net/if_arp.h`.  And yes, 0x323 turns out to not be any of them.  Moreover 0x323 is not any known device to `net/if_arp.h`

Here is a **test program** to populate `ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family` and print it:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stropts.h>

#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <net/if_arp.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd = -1;
    char *iface = argv[1];

    fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EPERM) {
            printf("UID/EUID 0 or capability CAP_NET_RAW required\n");

        } else {
            printf("socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name) -1);
    ifr.ifr_name[strlen(iface)] = '\0';

    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) < 0 )
    {
        printf("SIOCGIFHWADDR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "IFR: [%08x] sa_family [%02x]\n"
          , ifr.ifr_hwaddr, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family);
    return 0;
}
```

Half of it is simply copied from ettercap's code.  Anyhow, compilation shall be trivial `gcc -o prog prog.c` (given that the source is named `prog.c`) and you must run it with the interface name as its first argument.  e.g.

```
[root@haps ~]# /home/grochmal/tmp/libnet/test enp3s0
IFR: [24240001] sa_family [00]
[root@haps ~]# /home/grochmal/tmp/libnet/test wlp2s0
IFR: [22000001] sa_family [00]
```

(that's on my machine)

---

We can see that the `sa_family` is populated by:

```
ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr)
```

Which runs this:

```
  struct net_device *dev = dev_get_by_name_rcu(net, ifr->ifr_name);

  ...

  case SIOCGIFHWADDR:
          if (!dev->addr_len)
                  memset(ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 0,
                         sizeof(ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data));
          else
                  memcpy(ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, dev->dev_addr,
                         min(sizeof(ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data),
                             (size_t)dev->addr_len));
          ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_family = dev->type;
          return 0;
```

Where `dev_get_by_name_rcu` is a kernel macro that populates the `struct net_device`.  And since we have `ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_family = dev->type;` populates `sa_family` too.

---

I found a [bug report on the Kali Linux page](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=2496) about this `sa_family`, but kali does not use the most recent kernel.

Therefore I'd run the test program above to ensure that it prints:

```
IFR: [********] sa_family [323]
```

The test program needs to be run as root, since it uses a raw socket.

And then I'd try a newer kernel version to check whether the bug has been fixed in the 4.x kernel branch (e.g. gentoo or arch).  For example running a live CD with `gcc`.  The test program has no library requirements, therefore it can be easily compiled on a live CD.

That's a s deep as I can go into kernel code.  How exactly the `sa_family` is determined from the *device hash*, is beyond me.

Comment: So... I tried copying the test program and compiling it `/root/Desktop/test wlan0` but I can't, it says `/root/Desktop/test: line 12: int: command not found |
/root/Desktop/test: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token 'int' |
/root/Desktop/test: line 13: 'main(int argc, char** argv)'`

P.S. the "|" is a means I used to differentiate them apart

Comment: @Brooku - it is a C program.  You need to compile it with `gcc` (`gcc -o test test.c && ./test` using your naming convention), you're trying to run it as a script.  Try to [compile a `hello world`](http://www.linfo.org/create_c1.html) in C to get a feel for it.

Comment: If wlan0 is not in monitor mode that is what it outputs: `IFR: [c0000001] sa_family [00]` And when wlan0 is in monitor mode this is what it outputs: `IFR: [c0000323] sa_family [00]`. Sorry for the long wait

Comment: @Brooku - Ekhmm.... wait, why do you need the interface in monitor mode?  I cannot think of a reason why an ettercap MITM would need it (it will redirect the traffic to you).  Monitor mode is for tools like wireshark.  (i missed the "monitor mode" in your comment earlier, sorry)

Comment: It's because when I open the GUI of ettercap (I know I know, I have to get used to the text only interface) and choose my interface, there is not wlan0 unless it is in monitor mode. No problem!

Comment: @Brooku - I'm baffled at ettercap then.  But again, the test program did output a sensible `sa_family`, I would really try to switch to ettercap on a distro with a never kernel.  Although I'd also try to use the command line ettercap, it is not hard.  For example, `ettercap -M -T -i wlan0 /192.168.0.3/` would do a MITM on that IP.

Comment: It says: `MiTM method '-T' not supported...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42924/discussion-between-brooku-and-grochmal).